Deployment of Python Azure Function extremely slow
Deploying my Python Azure Function to a Function app takes a painful amount of time (sometimes >25 minutes).
The project only consists of 2 timer-trigger functions and the requirements.txt has the following entries:
azure-functions
pyodbc
sqlalchemy
numpy==1.26.4
pandas
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==2.2.0+cpu
darts

From what I can see, the most time is spent on deleting the old .python directory, (re-)installing all pip packages and then copying to the destination directory /home/site/wwwroot.
Is there a way to cache the installed packages, so I don't have to redeploy everything if I just make slight changes to the code? Are there other ways to speed up the process?

Add the application setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 in the function app and deploy again.

I actually tried that before. When trying to deploy, it then gives me this message: Removing WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting. So it just seems to be ignoring that setting.

Are you deploying using cli command?

Yes, this one: func azure functionapp publish 

Try zip deployment using the command az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n <app_name> --src <zip_file_path> after adding the application setting.

Yes, you can create a release pipeline and choose the Deploy a function app to Azure Functions task, there are many ways to do it by using Azure Repos or Github. please follow the documents below:

Continuous delivery with Azure Pipelines: link
Automate Azure Functions deployments with Azure Pipelines: link
Quickstart: Create a function in Azure with Python using Visual Studio Code: link


That seems to be a bit overkill for what I am trying to do. The reason why I want to speed up the deployment is that I run into a code error that I don't encounter locally. Trying to debug this issue when the code is running in the cloud is a nightmare because of the insane time it takes to redeploy the function.
